# Counting matching cells in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to count how many emails in my range appear in another worksheet range. I'm trying to  count how many people have unsubscribed from my newsletter list.

Workseet 1 has emails in column D, worksheet 2 has emails in column A. I want to count how many emails appear in both worksheets. I want these results to print in Worksheet 3.

I'm working in Worksheet 3 and i'm trying to achieve this with countifs. However I'm not having much luck.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(M4&"!A:A"),"<>",INDIRECT(M4&"!D:D"),"<>")
```

Example:

Worksheet 1 has my subscriber list
[image: worksheet 1]

Worksheet 2 - list of people who have unsubscribed recently

[image: Worksheet 2]

Worksheet 3 - expected result when I run the count. 2 people have been unsubscribed. 
[image]

Note: Worksheet 2 has a list of unsubscribed emails from all 40 locations locations (big list). Where worksheet 1 is only 2 locations (NY & LA in this example). I'm trying to find out how many unsubscribed for those two locations only.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C2:C8,$A$2:$A$11,0))))
```

[image]

`MATCH` returns an `#N/A!` error when it can't find the lookup value (unsubscribed e-mail address) in the lookup array (list of all addresses). `--NOT(ISERROR())` converts matches to 1's and non-matches (`#N/A!`) to zeroes. These are then summed to give the count.